# LuaTeX error "table index is nil" loading Cinzel OTF font with fontspec

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec

In a LuaLaTeX document I am creating with MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit (LuaTeX version beta-0.70.2-2012060719) in Windows 7, I get the following error:

```
! LuaTeX error ...)/MiKTeX 2.9/tex/luatex/luaotfload/otfl-font-otf.lua:553: table index is nil.  
<to be read again>   
                   \scan_stop:   
l.10     {Cinzel-Regular}`
```

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,twoside,10pt,extrafontsizes, onecolumn,openany,final]{memoir}  
\usepackage{luatextra} % Package also loads fontspec  
\newfontfamily\memfont[Path=./Fonts/,%  
    Extension=.otf,%  
    ItalicFont=CinzelDecorative-Regular,%  
    BoldFont=Cinzel-Bold,%  
    BoldItalicFont=CinzelDecorative-Bold]%  
    {Cinzel-Regular}  
\begin{document}  
\memfont  
blah!  
\end{document}
```

If I hit Enter to continue, I get a fontspec error saying that the font can't be found, which is silly. Other fonts load fine from the same location, and Cinzel loads without a hitch when run in XeLaTeX; neither spelling or directory information mistakes are the problem. It seems that there is something about Cinzel that LuaTeX just doesn't like--a missing "table" of some sort that Lua looks for in the font file that XeTeX just ignores, possibly. If anyone wants to poke around in the font itself with FontForge, Cinzel is freely distributed under the SIL Open Font License. Or is LuaTeX just being perverse? Any workaround for this? Or will I have to give up on Cinzel, a truly gorgeous font?

Comment: You may be running an antiquated version of LuaTeX, specifically, one that's no longer compatible with the luaotfload helper package. The version of LuaTeX that comes with TeXLive2013 (and MacTeX2013) is 0.76.0, whereas your TeX distribution apparently has version 0.70.2. (Versions of LuaTeX prior to 0.74 were based on Lua 5.1; more recent ones are based on Lua 5.2.) Try to do a full update of all MikTeX packages and see if the error persists.

Comment: no probleme here with TeXLive 2013 and Linux

Comment: Works fine for me with miktex 2.9, (32-bit). But I have Luatex `Version beta-0.76.0-2013062820`.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem due to outdated version of software

Comment: @egreg, yes as it turns out, it is. I didn't know that when I asked it.

Comment: @StonefeatherGrubbs Don't worry about this: you asked a good question, with an example and the error message. Since it turned out to be a software version problem, it's better to close it just to keep the site as tight as possible.

Answer (score 0):

@Mico and @Ulrike, yes! I updated MikTeX with its update utility, not only Lua to version 5.2 and other related, but luaoftload and fontspec as well. Cinzel now works fine in LuaLaTeX for me. I have been learning a lot about the TeX family of languages and programs here, but in many ways am still a relative newbie. Such a simple solution, but now I know my first step before posting should be to update my software. Thank you.